# How to use "cross" for finding the cross product of two vectors(OpenGL)?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I got a task to find if two vectors are coolinear(the z axis and the camera vector). I found a command named cross. The definition is this:

vec3 cross(vec3 x,vec3 y);

My logic tell me that the function is this

```
glm::vec3 Cproduct(glm::vec3 a, glm::vec3 b){

  return glm::vec3 cross(a,b);

}
```

But It doesnt work, it says ";" expected before cross. How to construct a function that takes 2 vectors, and returns the cross product of them two?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the return type when calling a function:

```
return cross(a, b);
```